# request for explaining code on form's reference

Tags: c#

How can the lines mark with * in `Form2` be referred back to `Form1`? 
I mean when `Form1` is instantiated, it can only be referenced by
the name Form1. But in the lines with *, `Form1` is used as a type
not a object. However, you can use the m_parent as reference for
`Form1` in the form called `Form2`
(I hope someone may get what I was trying to ask.)

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
*        private Form1 m_parent;

*        public Form2(Form1 frm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
*            m_parent = frm1;
        }
     }

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     }
```

Comment: *sniff*... smells like homework!

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a constructor for Form2 which takes a reference to a Form1 instance. On Form1 there may be code which looks something like:

```
var form = new Form2(this);
form.Show();
```

What is happening is you create Form2 with a reference to the current form and show it. It now has access to public members of Form1

Answer (score 0):

Both Form1 and Form2 are normal classes that can be instantiated.

In the Form2 class there is a constructor wich takes an instance of Form1 object as parameter. In the constructor's body the parameter (the reference to the Form1 object) is then storen in m_parent variable.